# Sass CSS dynamic & responsive column layout with mixin & variable

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass

In a constant effort to make CSS more compact, dynamic and maintainable using Sass I've stumbled upon the following: I have a webpage with *n*-column layout. Each item has some margin but every *n+1* item should have 0 margin, as it's the first item of a new row and should be aligned left completely.

Example: Desktop has a 4 column layout, so every 5-9-13th item should have 0 margin. Tablet has a 3 columns layout so every 4-7-10th item should have 0 margin and so on..

This is what I have

```
@mixin rowmargin($rows) {
    &:nth-child(#{$rows}n + 1){
         margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
div.col.list{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    @include rowmargin(4);
    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px){@include rowmargin(3);}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px){@include rowmargin(2);}
}
```

Which looks like this with 4 columns (good)
[image: 4 column lay-out]
And this with 3 columns (bad)
[image: 3 column lay-out]

As you can see the second item of the second row has 0 margin, but instead only the first item should have 0 margin.

Ps: don't mind the ingredients, they un-collapse (is there a word for this?) on tablet and mobile.

Comment: @Harbinger Sorry for cimmanon's curt response. What she is saying is that the issue you have is with the actual CSS (since Sass has to be converted to CSS before a browser can understand it). Sass questions should typically be about how to write/compile already-working CSS to Sass. So you should adjust your question to just show the CSS here, which is much more likely to get a constructive/helpful answer. Then you can convert that working CSS into Sass.

Comment: Thank you very much @TylerH for elaborating, that actually made sense. I will look for working css first and then try to work out the Sass. Thanks again